# How to place download in correct folder?

Tags: python, selenium

Right now, I have the underlying code. In short: it downloads files and places said files into a folder. The problem I'm running into is the following: currently, the download gets placed into folder x+1 (this is the client ID). The x+1 value isn't always the correct value (client ID), because some clients have been deleted. The website does show the client ID text like this:
`<span id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_lblID" class="invoer_label">2</span>` and `<input name="ctl00$CPH$Main$ctl00$TxtPatientNr" type="text" value="2" readonly="readonly" id="TxtPatientNr" class="textbox_algemeen_klein textbox_phone_full_width textbox_tablet_50procent">`, where '2' is the actual client ID. Can I use this value, to put the downloaded files into the correct folder? Or do you have any idea how I can make sure the download is placed in the correct folder?

```
#Function to export data
def loop_function():

    #Search client
    searchCustomerButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ibSearchPatient"]')
    searchCustomerButton.click()

    #Click on show filter
    showCustomerFilter = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid_Patienten_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_Arrow"]')
    showCustomerFilter.click()

    time.sleep(5)

    #Click on show 1000
    selectCustomerFilter = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid_Patienten_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[6]')
    selectCustomerFilter.click()    

    #Loop client ID's
    followLoop = range(985, 1015)
    for x in followLoop:

        xpath = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid_Patienten_ctl00__'
        xpath += str(x)
        xpath += '"]/td[3]'
        
        #Click on cliënt ID
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

        #Click on Zorgtraject
        zorgtrajectButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span')
        zorgtrajectButton.click()

        #Loop Zorgtraject ID's
        followLoop2 = range(0,10)
        for i in followLoop2:
            try:
                xpath2 = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid1_ctl00__'
                xpath2 += str(i)
                xpath2 += '"]/td[2]'

                #Click on Zorgtraject ID
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()

                #Dossier button
                dossierButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[5]/a/span/span/span')
                dossierButton.click()

                #Dropdown select
                dropdownSelector = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_Arrow"]')
                dropdownSelector.click()

                #Prevent not interactable error
                time.sleep(1)

                #Select 50
                selectDropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[4]')
                selectDropdown.click()

                #Load files to be downloaded
                time.sleep(1)

                #Check all documents
                tickDossier = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_headerChkboxPrint"]')
                tickDossier.click()

                #Click print
                printButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_btnPrintBehandelverloop"]')
                printButton.click()

                #Click on Zorgtraject ID
                zorgtrajectButton2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span')
                zorgtrajectButton2.click()

            #If no Zorgtraject ID, start function over
            except NoSuchElementException:
                src = 'C:\\Users\\sohan\\Downloads'
                dst = 'C:\\Users\\sohan\\Documents\\Werk\\BIA Solutions\\Huid & Laserkliniek Delft\\Data\\' + str(x+1)

                files = [i for i in os.listdir(src) if i.startswith("behandel") and path.isfile(path.join(src, i))]
                for f in files:
                    shutil.move(path.join(src, f), dst)

                #Search client
                searchCustomerButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ibSearchPatient"]')
                searchCustomerButton.click()

                #Click on show filter
                showCustomerFilter = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid_Patienten_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_Arrow"]')
                showCustomerFilter.click()

                time.sleep(5)

                #Click on show 1000
                selectCustomerFilter = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid_Patienten_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[6]')
                selectCustomerFilter.click()     
                break

loop_function()
```

Comment: I see I already answered you this question previously. What is missing with my previous answer?

Comment: Hi @Prophet, sometimes the XPath skipped a number, because the client was deleted. This meant that the client ID was not equal to 'x+1'. I managed to figure it out though!